# how to handle Selenium stale element exception

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to iterate through options stored in a list Web Element using an enhancement for loop to search for a specific option and click on it. The program seems to work just fine when I run it, but I keep getting a stale element reference exception error. Can anyone help me find the solution to this problem

```
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.delta.com/");
    
    driver.findElement(By.id("fromAirportName")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("search_input")).sendKeys("New York");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
    List <WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span[class *= 'airport-city']"));
    
    for (WebElement option : options)
    {
        if(option.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("New York-Kennedy, NY"))
        {
            option.click();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be slowness of element load sometime. Either you need to put too much wait time before getting the list of options or get the option list updated inside the loop. Following code should work.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.delta.com/");

driver.findElement(By.id("fromAirportName")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("search_input")).sendKeys("New York");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
List <WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span[class *= 'airport-city']"));

for (int i=0;i<options.size(); i++)
{
    options = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span[class *= 'airport-city']"));
    if(option.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("New York-Kennedy, NY"))
    {
        option.get(i).click();
    }
}
```